# Global variables not being attached to the `global` object on MeteorJS packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm writing a Meteor package and I've found that global variables are not being attached to the `global` object, **only** on Meteor packages (on normal Meteor projects this doesn't happen). To reproduce, write the following on a Meteor package:

```
x = 1
global.x = 2

console.log(x)        // 1
console.log(global.x) // 2
```

The behaviour that I would expect is `x` and `global.x` having the same value (`2`).

Is this expected on Meteor packages? Is there a special wrapper around Node's `gloabal` object?

Thanks!

Edit after David Weldon's response:

Context: I'm trying to follow https://github.com/feross/standard so I'm removing all global variable declarations on the `my_variable` style, and using `global.my_variable` instead. I'm not being able to export variables stored on `global` using `api.export`, as `api.export('global.my_variable', ...)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are wrapped in a closure to prevent global leaks. To expose a symbol outside of your package, use [api.export](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export) in your [package.js](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs).

Comment: Thanks for your response David, since your response I've updated my question to show that I'm not being able to use `api.export` to export my globals. Please check.

Comment: Well you need to ignore that standards doc for this case. `export` attempts to make application-level global variables out of the package-level globals. By declaring your variables as `global.` you are circumventing this process. Just drop the `var` on the variables you need to use `api.export` on - that's how all meteor packages are written.